# Connecting T6i to Elgato Game Capture HD

Tags: streaming, dslr, canon, hdmi

I recently purchased an Elgato HD for my MacBook Air, and I am fairly new at learning how everything comes together, so bear with me.

I am trying to connect my Canon T6i as a capture device and I have been semi successful, but I have some other questions. I have connected the camera to the capture card via HDMI, but it can only be recognized through USB and I'm not fond of the delay. Is there any way around this? I may be wrong, and correct me if I am, but I was under the impression that I could use the Elgato HD to capture video through HDMI.

My setup right now has HDMI from the T6i to the capture card, and another HDMI from the capture card to an HDMI adapter. I'm assuming this is my issue here, but I have not found any clear answers anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Witch HDMI adapter are you talking about? You can only connect your Elgato to your Mac via usb, no other way. The delay in some frames is pretty normal in a MacBook Air.

Answer (score 0):

HDMI cable from camera should go to Elgato, USB cable from Elgato should go into your MacBook USB port.

If you want to reduce delay, you need to get a capture card that doesn't compress the video, instead of the Elgato. Something like an Epiphan AV.io, which has one frame latency.

Comment: It should be noted that there's likely a relatively significant delay on the output from the T6i as well.  Even my 5D Mark iii has a delay of around 300-400ms.  It's enough that it causes a majorly noticeable delay when trying to use it with a live video switcher.